# JAVASCRIPT: how can I remove a json object in json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

how can I remove a json object in json object?

```
[
    [
        {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},          
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"1"}
   ],
   [
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"20"},               
        {"name":"coupon","value":""},
        {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"}, 
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"2"}
   ],
   [
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"7"},
       {"name":"coupon","value":"1"},
       {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"3"}
   ],
   [   {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"1"},
       {"name":"coupon","value":"1"},
       {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"4"}
   ]
]
```

I save this json in `ordering`

Now I want remove

```
   [   {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"1"},
       {"name":"coupon","value":"1"},
       {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"4"}
   ]
```

My key is `extera_Ordering_json[id]` (it is not unique)

I do this:

```
ordering = JSON.parse(ordering);
var temp;
$.each(ordering, function(idx, obj)
{
    if(obj.Ordering_json[id] != 4)// not works
    {
        temp[] = obj;
    }
    temp[] = obj
}
ordering = JSON.stringify(temp);
```

Comment: `idx` != `id` ... :-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"extera_Ordering_json[id]"` is simply a string so you need to iterate all the objects in each array and find the one that has that string as `name` and check the `value` of the same object

Here's a map and filter approach

```js
var data = [
    [
        {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},          
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"1"}
   ],
   [
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"20"},               
        {"name":"coupon","value":""},
        {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"}, 
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"2"}
   ],
   [
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"7"},
       {"name":"coupon","value":"1"},
       {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"3"}
   ],
   [   {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"1"},
       {"name":"coupon","value":"1"},
       {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"4"}
   ]
]
var searchVal = 1
data=data.map(function(arr){
   return arr.filter(function(o){
      return o.name !== "extera_Ordering_json[id]" || +o.value !== searchVal
   })
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using id instead of idx. try this

```
if(obj.Ordering_json[idx] != 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use splice method

```
ordering = [ /*Array without json parsing*/ ];
var indexToDelete = 3;
ordering.splice( indexToDelete, 1); 
// 1 indicates only one element from array 
console.log(ordering);
```

Comment: thanks. your answer is by index. I want delete it by `Ordering_json[id]` value

Comment: don't use `delete` on arrays, it leaves holes and length will still remain the same

Comment: Right @charlietfl , I forget to mention. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `splice` method on your JSON array to remove an element at a specific index:

```js
var ordering = JSON.stringify([
    [
        {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},          
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"1"}
   ],
   [
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"20"},               
        {"name":"coupon","value":""},
        {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"}, 
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"2"}
   ],
   [
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"7"},
       {"name":"coupon","value":"1"},
       {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"3"}
   ],
   [   {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"1"},
       {"name":"coupon","value":"1"},
       {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"4"}
   ]
])

temp = JSON.parse(ordering);
temp.splice(3, 1)
ordering = JSON.stringify(temp);
console.log(ordering)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case `extera_Ordering_json[id]` is not key, it is value of `name`

```js
    var ordering = [
        [
            {"name": "formtype", "value": "ordering"},
            {"name": "extera_Ordering_json[id]", "value": "1"}
        ],
        [
            {"name": "extera_Ordering_json[count]", "value": "20"},
            {"name": "coupon", "value": ""},
            {"name": "formtype", "value": "ordering"},
            {"name": "extera_Ordering_json[id]", "value": "2"}
        ],
        [
            {"name": "extera_Ordering_json[count]", "value": "7"},
            {"name": "coupon", "value": "1"},
            {"name": "formtype", "value": "ordering"},
            {"name": "extera_Ordering_json[id]", "value": "3"}
        ],
        [{"name": "extera_Ordering_json[count]", "value": "1"},
            {"name": "coupon", "value": "1"},
            {"name": "formtype", "value": "ordering"},
            {"name": "extera_Ordering_json[id]", "value": "4"}
        ]
    ];
    var temp = [];
    $.each(ordering, function (key1, obj1) {
        $.each(obj1, function (key2, obj2) {
            if (obj2.name == 'extera_Ordering_json[id]' && obj2.value == 4) {
                delete ordering[key1];
            }
        });
        if(ordering[key1] != null){
            temp.push(ordering[key1]);
        }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
var ordering = [
    [
        {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},          
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"1"}
    ],
    [
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"20"},               
        {"name":"coupon","value":""},
        {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"}, 
        {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"2"}
    ],
    [
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"7"},
       {"name":"coupon","value":"1"},
       {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"3"}
    ],
    [   
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[count]","value":"1"},
       {"name":"coupon","value":"1"},
       {"name":"formtype","value":"ordering"},
       {"name":"extera_Ordering_json[id]","value":"4"}
    ]
];
    var sVal = 4;
    var indexToRemove = false;
    ordering.forEach(function(element, index) {
       element.forEach(function(subelement) {
           if (subelement.name == "extera_Ordering_json[id]" 
              && parseInt(subelement.value) == sVal){
              indexToRemove = index;
           }
       });
    });

    if (false !== indexToRemove) {
        ordering.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    }
```